# parallel requests with gunicorn on heroku

Tags: multithreading, heroku, flask, gunicorn

I've pushed an I/O bound gunicorn\flask service to heroku. [Heroku docs advise to either increase the number of gunicorn workers or to use async threads such as gevent](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-gunicorn). I tried the following `Procfile`s but still the service handles the file upload requests serially. I've added no application level locks.

Multiple processes `Procfile`:

```
web: gunicorn service:app --log-file=- --workers 4
```

Multiple threads `Procfile`:

```
web: gunicorn service:app --log-file=- --threads 4 --worker-class gevent
```

All the service does is receive JSON request, de-serialize it and upload the binary to S3. The logs suggest the limiting factor is that each request is handled only after the last has completed.

**Is there something inherent to heroku or to flask that prevents multiple requests being handled in parallel?**

AFAIK the code is agnostic to the number of workers, but is it also agnostic to the number of threads? Or should I add some kind of support in the code.

Comment: Any reason you're not doing uploads directly to S3?

Comment: @YuvalAdam - Is there a way to allow the client application to upload directly to S3 while still maintaining control and preventing hackers from uploading terabytes of junk?

Comment: of course. You can generate signed URLs that allow an end client to POST data directly to the bucket, all the while conforming to a signed policy that can limit file type, file size, key name, ACL and has a proper TTL after which the client needs to poll again to receive a new signed URL. See https://aws.amazon.com/articles/1434